# Android custom adapter getView() NullPointerException out of nowhere!

Tags: android

I've got a custom Adapter to supply data for ListView. Everything worked fine, but 'suddenly'(I don't have another word for what's now happening) my app started crashing while loading my Activity with listview:

```
W/dalvikvm(  228): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

E/AndroidRuntime(  228): java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at AdvertisementListAdapter.getView(AdvertisementListAdapter.java:72)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

E/AndroidRuntime(  228):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My getView method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); 
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgItemImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgItemImage);
            holder.tvItemTitle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemTitle);
            holder.tvItemDetails=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemDetails);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        holder.tvItemTitle.setText(data.get(position).getYear()+" "+data.get(position).getTitle());

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(data.get(position).getPrice());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(data.get(position).getCity());
        holder.tvItemDetails.setText(sb.toString());


        String imageUrl="http://myuri/"+data.get(position).getUrlList().get(0)+"/p-t.jpeg";
        holder.imgItemImage.setTag(imageUrl);

        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, activity, holder.imgItemImage);

        return view;    
    }
```

When getView is first called, `convertView=null`, so `ViewHolder` object is created. But after calling `findViewById(...)` all members of ViewHolder class are still null. So, here are the origins `NullPointerException`. View inflating is successul as I can see during debug, `view` object contains `RelativeLayout` with it's children. 
The worst thing is that I haven't changed this part of app before it started crashing!
This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Is the class shown the one that is throwing the null pointer?  If so, which line is 72?

Comment: 72 is holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag(); But when I debug app 72 line is not reached when getView is first called because convertView is null, so during debug I get exception after holder.tvItemTitle.setText(data.get(position).getYear()+" "+data.get(position).getTitle());

Comment: Is it possible that your data variable is stale?  Could the following return null? data.get(position)

Comment: During debug i checked it, data is not null. I get nulls in ViewHolder views, after findViewById() and I don't know why. Everything worked fine till tomorrow night...

Comment: It may be to your advantage to break down your code and put each call on its own line (at least for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to rebuild the application from scratch?
Project -> Clean

Answer (score 3):

Try rebuilding the R class. In eclipse it's as simple as changing something in the layout XML and saving again to get the R.id.* up to date. Sometimes they get screwed up.

Answer (score 3):

So, that's solved. I tried rebulding, cleaning project. Then I deleted it from workspace and reopened - it worked. That is Eclipse bug, that's horrible, I wasted couple of hours! Thanks to all for responses! Sorry for disturbing...