# App keeps crashing upon running the build

Tags: java, android, crash, classcastexception

To the kind moderator who marked this thread as a duplicate: I visited the "original" thread and it has nothing (that I can see) that could help me. Please re open this thread.

My app keeps crashing when I run this build (it's a basic login and registration form). The problem is for sure in the LoginActivity.java code, but I don't know what the problem is.

Here's the RegistrationActivity.java code

```
package com.example.sean.cookappreal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etEmailAddress = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.etEmailAddress);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    }
}
```

Here's the LoginActvitity.java code:

```
package com.example.sean.cookappreal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView registerLink = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

        registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent registerIntent = new 
Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And finally here's the UserAreaActivity.java code (this is just a very simple home welcome screen).

```
package com.example.sean.cookappreal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;




public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) 
     findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final TextView welcomeMessage = (TextView) 
     findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomeMsg);

    }
}
```

Here's my manifest code as asked for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.sean.cookappreal">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".UserAreaActivity"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here's the log cat information.

```
07-26 17:27:17.491 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal E/Zygote: v2
07-26 17:27:17.491 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0033
07-26 17:27:17.491 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10238
07-26 17:27:17.491 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
07-26 17:27:17.501 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-26 17:27:17.501 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.sean.cookappreal 
07-26 17:27:17.501 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-26 17:27:17.541 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
07-26 17:27:17.541 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
07-26 17:27:17.581 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
07-26 17:27:17.721 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:17.951 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.021 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.081 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.151 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.211 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.271 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.331 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.401 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.471 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.531 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.sean.cookappreal-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-26 17:27:18.531 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.sean.cookappreal-1/lib/arm
07-26 17:27:18.541 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-26 17:27:18.671 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-26 17:27:18.891 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-26 17:27:18.891 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.sean.cookappreal, PID: 13115
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sean.cookappreal/com.example.sean.cookappreal.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                  at com.example.sean.cookappreal.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:19)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
07-26 17:32:19.201 13115-13115/com.example.sean.cookappreal I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13115 SIG: 9
```

Here's my Activity Register Layout

[image]

Here's my Activity Login Layout

[image]

Comment: Do you have entries in your app manifest XML file for all the activities involved here?  Now would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger. If you could tell us exactly where the code is crashing, that would save us a lot of guess work here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The part that causes the code to crash is the LoginActivity.java code, from the final variable declarations to the end of that docs code.

Comment: @MaheshGawhane What do you mean by error log? I'm running this build on my phone, so the app just opens and immediately crashes with the message "Unfortunately, cookAppReal has stopped".

Comment: See this for logs: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html or directly https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint on the first line of the `onCreate()` method of the `LoginActivity`?  Let's see where it is dying.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It looks like its something to do with not being able to cast android.widget.RelativeLayout to android.widget.TextView?

Comment: OK what type of widget in your login layout has ID `tvRegisterHere` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's a checkedTextView.

Comment: Humm, the design view doesn't help, we need the text version(switch tabs in the left corner). Also, seems you removed the error logs, does it mean you solved that?

Comment: @Adinia , no, they seemed unreadable to me and I was worried it wasn't what people were looking for but since you seem to understand them I'll put them back. I'll also upload the text versions now.

Comment: Have you read the link about logs that I posted earlier? If the Debugger it's not your best friend, you can't do anything. When you have a crash, you have to look for error type logs (E/..), starting by 'Caused  by:', then research for that, if you don't know what it means. In this case, it's clearly stated that there is a ClassCastException in LoginActivity on line 19. `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.sean.cookappreal.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:19)`

Comment: You seriously need to learn some basics about android studio and debugging .

Comment: While I agree that this is not a duplicate of the question chosen by ModularSynth(not a moderator, btw, just an Android expert), once you post your real error, it'll most surely be a duplicate of another existing question, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076490/469983

Comment: issue fixed????

Comment: If the OP doesn't **stop changing this post every now and then**, the question will always be invalid for any comment or answer we could provide. Originally, it asked about this error: `The processing instruction target matching “[xX][mM][lL]” is not allowed`. Hence, the duplicate.

Comment: Issue not fixed, still looking for help. Something in the LoginActvitity.java (Ik cause app loads and runs when I delete the code i added to it) is causing the app to instacrash. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as I could see, you use the ID's for etUsername and etPassword twice. You could use them just use once a time per the complete app. Also it's not possible to find and element by the id, which is not in the layout.

Tarik